# GnuPG pinentry depending on GUI presence

Tags: macos, gnupg

On MacOSX I'm using `gnupg21` in order to sign `git commit`. Depending on project I'm currently working sometime I'm using IDE (here `IntellijIDEA`) to interact with `git` and sometime directly in `terminal`.

I had to setup

```
pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry-mac
```

to be able to continue working on `IntellijIDEA`.

However I'm not really fan about prompting GUI when I'm using `terminal`. Do you think is possible to configure `gnupg21` to choose `pinentry` program regarding the situation?

- On GUI -> `/usr/local/bin/pinentry-mac`
- On terminal -> `/usr/local/bin/pinentry`

---

Edit: My current config files

**gpg-agent.conf**

```
enable-ssh-support
default-cache-ttl 14400
max-cache-ttl 86400
log-file /var/log/gpg-agent.log
pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry-mac
```

**gpg.conf**

```
keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net
no-tty
use-agent
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Running Multiple `gpg-agent`s

GnuPG's `gpg-agent` could be configured to use different sockets before GnuPG 2.1; you could have used different `gpg-agent`s running in parallel with different configuration (pinentry implementations).

With GnuPG 2.1, this is not possible any more. GnuPG since 2.1 always uses a fixed socket path.

#### Pinentry Switching

The only clean possibility to enable such a feature is probably writing a pinentry "switch" implementation, deciding which actual pinentry to call depending on whether called from a command line or the GUI (for example, depending on what `DISPLAY` or `tty` variables are set).

#### Loopback Pinentry Mode

An alternative would be to use the loopback pinentry feature, which is disabled in `gpg-agent` by default for security reasons. Pinentry loopback will have `gpg-agent` query `gpg` for the passphrase instead of the out-of-band pinentry password query. This potentially opens security issues, as the rather large and complex GnuPG application (with a larger chance of vulnerabilities) gets access to the passphrase and thus the private key, which would otherwise be limited to the `gpg-agent` and pinentry implementation.

To do so anyway, add a line `allow-loopback-pinentry` in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`, `killall gpg-agent` (so it is restarted with the option enabled on the next time GnuPG wants to use it). When you want to use GUI pinentry, start GnuPG as normal; for command line operations, call `gpg21 --pinentry-mode loopback` instead (which of course could be an alias for `gpg21`).

Comment: Pretty clear answer. I wont rollback gnupg version and security concern for such feature is important. So I really think I would write my own switch as you described

Answer (score 7):

Sorry for the late answer but I had the same question and found a solution that seems cleaner than changing the `pinentry-program` configuration and restarting gpg-agent every time.

Although it's not documented anywhere outside of the source, `pinentry-mac` will fall back to the curses CLI pin entry method if the `PINENTRY_USER_DATA` environment variable is set to `USE_CURSES=1`. You can leave pinentry-mac as the default in your gpg-agent.conf and slap:

```
export PINENTRY_USER_DATA="USE_CURSES=1"
```

in your bash profile or equivalent.

Comment: Somehow, when I implement the above, all keys output a `*` in pinentry-curses including backspaces. Anyone has encountered this bug?